# Angular AOT compilation error : Internal state: StaticSymbols in summaries can't have members

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-compiler-cli

We are trying to perform ahead of time ( aot ) compilation for our angular 2 project and we are running into a error :

> **Error: Internal state: StaticSymbols in summaries can't have members! {"filePath":"C:/Users/bhavy/Documents/projects/kairos/projects/KairosUI/node_modules/daypilot-pro-angular/daypilot-angular.min.d.ts","name":"DayPilot","members":["Angular","Scheduler"]}**

> Error: Internal state: StaticSymbols in summaries can't have members! {"filePath":"C:/Users/bhavy/Documents/projects/kairos/projects/KairosUI/node_modules/daypilot-pro-angular/daypilot-angular.min.d.ts","name":"DayPilot","members":["Angular","Scheduler"]}
>       at AotSummaryResolver._assertNoMembers (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:26300:23)
>       at AotSummaryResolver.resolveSummary (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:26308:18)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._loadSummary (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18032:70)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18226:56)
>       at C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18318:72
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18313:53)
>       at addNgModule (C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25053:62)
>       at C:\Users\bhavy\Documents\projects\kairos\projects\kairosUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25064:18
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       Compilation failed.

**What does this error mean ?
What Static Symbols are we referring to here ?**

We cannot attempt to fix it unless we know what the error actually is.
Any help/suggestions in this regard would be much appreciated.

PS : we tried to raise the issue on the angular github issue [tracker](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14063) but got told the stackoverflow might be be better place to raise such *support issues*.

Comment: does you project compile without errors

Comment: @RahulSingh, we are using webpack to perform compilation in development and production environment. And yes it compiles just fine.

Comment: can you please post the code for this component daypilot-angular i think it is pointing to somewhere in this class

Comment: Its pretty hard to debug it like this its refering to that file , many a times due to improper method arguments or references in the component lead to the aot not compiling, you need to check that class.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forums.daypilot.org/Topic.aspx/3703/error-while-compiling-angular2-project-using-aot-compiler-s) on the Daypilot forums, AOT is not yet supported. It is something that they are currently working on, but no estimated date of delivery has been given.

Comment: but then , what could be a possible solution, problem in my project is in prodduction also , it is a JIT build because of daypilot and the app has become too slow as parse html is performing operations at run time. any ideas if I can exclude daypilot from ngc compilation ?